# Tell if it's the last bar on the chart in SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

If I have a bar chart in an SSRS report, how can I tell (using an expression) if it's the last bar of the chart? Is there a way to take the index or position, or see if the next is null?

Is there such a thing as Chart.bar.index()  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to check whether the current value of the Category Group is the same as the maximum value. For example, if your graph is reporting from Dataset1 and is grouped by `date`, then your expression might look like:

```
=iif(Fields!date.Value=Max(Fields!date.Value, "DataSet1"),"Specific","Default")
```